# Assign labels text to a string array

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Pw3.png)

I'm developing a quiz game for college.

What I want is to stock all of the 8 label.Text values into an array , or in anything that I can iterate over.

```
string[] raspunsuri = new string[8] { label2.Text , label3.Text , etc ...};
```

Error code is: CS0236.

I'm new to C# and even googling things up didn't help me much .

I tried declaring a single value at a time

```
string test = label.text;
```

but I get the same error.

Tried declaring inside a public method I created but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your full code?

I'm assuming you are using WinForms, or something similar where you are getting text from label.

I would guess that you may not be writing this code inside a method. Try writing this code for initializing your array inside of a method. Your error code points to that you are trying to write this code outside of a method or function.
Instead of

```
string[] raspunsuri = new string[8] { label2.Text , label3.Text , etc ...};
```

Try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] raspunsuri = new string[8] { label2.Text , label3.Text , etc ...};
}
```

Or you can put it in any method that you would like.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also , all the corect answears are stocked inside the 'raspunsuri' array of strings . If I want to set the coresponding text label color white , for ex I have label1, label 2 ,label 3 ,etc .. label 8 , and If the inputed answear coresponds to the label.Text  , make the Label.text white. This is my code  :                                                                                              
              foreach (string a in raspunsuri)
                    if (a == textBox1.Text)
                        label[i] = Color.White; // I know label[i] won't work , just the ideea

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. If `label`s can *change* their `Text`s I suggest implementing a *property* to get *fresh* values:

```
// Read-only property: whenever you read it, 
// it creates and return an array with fresh values
string[] raspunsuri => new string[] { label2.Text, label3.Text, etc ...};
```

If `label`s don't change their values, you should *declare* `string[] Raspunsuri` field, but assign values later; assuming that you have WinForms it can be something like this:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form 
{
    string[] raspunsuri;

    ...

    public MyForm()
    {
        // Let labels be created and obtain their values
        InitializeComponent();

        // Time to assign values to the field
        raspunsuri = new string[] { label2.Text, label3.Text, etc ... };  
    }

    ...
}
```

Same with just one label: just try *property*:

```
string test => label.Text;
```